# Create App with React Native and typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create an app with React Native and TypeScript, but it's not working. I use the following commands:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

And the log error:

```
Yarn version: 
  1.22.15

Node version: 
  16.10.0

Platform: 
  win32 x64

Trace: 
  Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript: Not found
      at Request.params.callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66140:18)
      at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:140885:22)
      at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141857:10)
      at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141779:12)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Comment: According to the React Native docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#getting-started-with-typescript): "Note: If the above command is failing, you may have an old version of react-native or react-native-cli installed globally on your system. To fix the issue try uninstalling the CLI:

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli or yarn global remove react-native-cli
and then run the npx command again."

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working after I've uninstalled reat-native-cli

Answer (score 1):

you should first uninstall the previous react-native-cli to install the newest with the typescript features.

1- npm uninstall -g react-native-cli.

2- yarn global add @react-native-community/cli

3- react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript

Comment: I was trying this way `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`. Just dropped `npx` and voilà

Answer (score 0):

You can try

npx react-native@0.65 init MyTestApp --version 0.65 --template react-native-template-typescript@6.7